# Hard Drives shows up in Finder, but not Desktop

Tags: macos, finder, hard-drive, desktop

In the past when I have plugged in external hard-drives they would always show up on the desktop. I'm not sure if it is because of a software update or the drive itself but it's no longer showing up.

The drive is working because if I go to Finder I can access the drive.

How can I change the settings so that drives show up on the desktop when they are plugged in?

I'm using OSX version: 10.7.3.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probably have accidentally unchecked "Hard disks" from the Finder Preference pane (accessible with <kbd>⌘</kbd> +  <kbd>,</kbd> ). Just check the box,

[image]

and you should be good to go!